# How to share image on Facebook with Caption from android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-share

I tried sharing an Image with Caption on Facebook with the help of Facebook API and the code as below:

```
SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                    .setBitmap(image)
                    .setCaption("Caption is Important")
                    .build();
            SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                    .addPhoto(photo)
                    .build();

            shareDialog.show(content);
```

It open up the ShareDialog but the caption wont appear in it the dialog

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/policy#control, 2.3 - you are not allowed to specify the caption for the user in the first place, they have to type it in themselves.

Comment: Why do they have an Function for it then?

Comment: it was available earlier, now the user has to type it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the facebook documentation shared CBroe:

https://developers.facebook.com/policy#control

According to its policy 2.3 it states that

> Don't prefill captions, comments, messages, or the user message parameter of posts with content a person or business didn’t create, even if the person can edit or remove the content before sharing. You may use our Share Dialogs to prefill a single hashtag in a post, but don't prefill any content a person or business didn't create via the API.

So we are no longer allowed to pre-fill captions for images by using shareDialog or by using any other method.

Answer (score 0):

You can add caption with the given method. But at share dialog of facebook. You have to manually type your caption.[image]

Comment: You can add caption with the given method means?Is it possible using some other way ?